# Load Data to Hive array column

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I have two Hive tables as shown below, along with their columns

```
Tbl_Customer
Id
Name

Tbl_Cntct
Id
Phone
```

One Id can have many phone numbers so I have a table

```
Tbl_All
Id
Name
Phn_List ARRAY
```

My question is on how to load data from Tbl_Custome and Tbl_Cntct into Tbl_All.
I can do it in PIG, but want to do same in Hive.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Insert overwrite table Tbl_All
select cus.id,cus.name,collect_set(ctc.phone)
from Tbl_Customer cus join Tbl_Cntct ctc on cus.id = ctc.id
group by cus.id,cus.name
```

The `collect_set` UDAF is a function collects the column into an array with no duplicates.If you want to remain all the value include duplicated ones,use `collect_list` function